# Possible to use cross validation for final evaluation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, unbalanced-classes, model-evaluation

Can k-fold cross validation be used for a final evaluation of a model? I have highly imbalanced and small dataset, which would make it difficult to evaluate on a small test-sest. I know that k-fold cross validation is usually just used for model selection, but if i do not select a model and dont optimize any hyperparameters or choose a model by evaluating its results on the data, is it okay to use cross fold validation instead of hold out? If yes, does anyone have exmaples of research where this was done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be fine as no information from the test set in each fold has "leaked" in to the design of the classifier, so it would give an [unbiased performance estimate](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf) (of the performance of a classifier trained on 100*(k-1)/k percent of the available data).

However, if it is a small dataset, I would recommend using bootstrapping instead as this is likely to have a lower variance and gives an unbiased performance estimate.  I'd also used bagging (which you get for free) which is likely to give better performance, and the out-of-bag estimate can be used for evaluating the performance of the ensemble.

Comment: I am not familiar with bootstrapping, I will look into it. Do you know of any research I could cite where it was done like this? I could not find any but i would really prefer to be able to cite some.

Comment: It is difficult to think of a specific paper as I mostly work on models which require hyper-parameter tuning, however I think k-fold cross-validation is sufficiently common as not to really need a reference to a previous study ( a reference to a good text book should be fine)

Comment: For bootstrap validation see e.g. [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms) - book, course notes, or live course.